# Gaussian KDE of n-dimensional data : leading minor of the array is not positive definite

Tags: python, scipy, kernel-density

I have two subsets of n-dimensional data `A` and `B`, and I would like to know, for each sample in `B` the density of samples from `A` around it.

Example datasets with 5 samples in 3 dimensions

```py
A = np.array([[-2.44528668, -0.09326276, -1.06527892],
       [-1.35144799, -1.45507518, -0.02096   ],
       [-0.5788315 , -1.48932706, -0.28496559],
       [-1.60224949, -0.76823424, -0.11548589],
       [-1.15768561, -0.74704022, -0.14744463]])

B = np.array([[-1.84134663, -1.42036525, -1.38819347],
       [-2.58165693, -2.49423057, -1.57609454],
       [-0.78776371, -0.79168188,  0.21967791],
       [-1.0165618 , -1.78509185, -0.68373997],
       [-1.21764947, -0.43215885, -0.34393573]])
```

I tried to do the following

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

kernel = gaussian_kde(A)
densities = kernel(B)
```

but this raised

```
LinAlgError: 2-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite
```

What does this error mean, and how can I get the density of points from `A` for each sample in `B`?

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong No, I want the kde for all five samples, not just the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message I get when I do

```
kernel = gaussian_kde(A)
densities = kernel(B[0])
```

I figured that `gaussian_kde` considers each column to be one sample, and each line to be the coordinates in the nth dimension, so I should be using the transpose of my arrays instead.

So to get the result I want, I should be doing

```
kernel = gaussian_kde(A.T)
densities = kernel(B.T)
```

But I still don't know what the error message I was getting means.

Comment: Hi @usernumber I am facing the same problem did you figure out why this error message? and how to solve it?

Comment: @azeez Do you get the same message when using the transposed arrays?

Comment: No without using the transposed arrays

Comment: @azeez Make sure that each column in your arrays is one sample. If that is not the case, then use the transposed arrays.